# how to access a specific data in two columns using if and statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

[My Data Frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jm1Gr.jpg)

My Code:

```
a = 10001
b = "01.01.2001"
if a == np.any(df["Token_ID"]) and b == np.any(df["Date_of_birth"]):
     print("yes")
else:
     print("no")
```

The above code works for only the first row in the data frame. If I provide a = 10012 and b = "01.01.2012" then it prints no. can anyone explain this?

Thank You.

Mismatched Data

```py
a = 10011
b = "01.01.2001"
if (a in df["Token_ID"].values) and (b in df["Date_of_birth"].values):
    print("yes")
else:
    print("no")
```

What I am trying to do is if both values matched then it will print the remaining columns except these two columns from the dataframe

Comment: welcome to SO! please have a look [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question with more information

Comment: You put `any` in the wrong place. Look at my answer carefully.

Comment: This should print yes with mismatched data. Becase it searches on the entire column, if there is match between a and Token_ID regardless the value of b in the same row.

Comment: You want to compare a and b values with Token_ID and Date_of_birth in the same row, right?

Comment: yes I want to compare a and b values with Token_ID and Date_of_birth in the same row

Comment: I corrected my code :)

Comment: Please post it.

Comment: It would be good if you explain in your question what you are trying to do.

Comment: If both values matched then it will print the remaining columns except these two columns from the dataframe

Comment: Did the new version answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The current code** compares `a` value with all values `Token_ID` column which results a column of `True` and `False` values and the same with `b` value with values of `Date_of_birth` column. Then, you put `and` operator between two boolean columns.

**How to correct the current version:** You should use `&` and `any` operator.

```
if any((a == df["Token_ID"]) & (b == df["Date_of_birth"])):
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. For the first statement it print no even if the data were present. For second statement it  works but if I provide mismatched token_id and date_of_birth then it print also as yes I don't know why.

Comment: @Kenny I corrected the answer

Comment: your both statement works perfectly. But if I provide mismatched Token_ID and Date_of _birth then it print also as yes can you explain please? If I provide mismatched Token_ID and Date_of _birth then it print  no but it print as yes.

Comment: I tried with my own dataframe, it works correctly. Could you please post your mismatch values with the new version of code?

Comment: I posted the mismatched version of code for your reference as mismatched data